# c++ win32 changing the application display name

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, winapi

I've developed a win32 api application using c++. It was developed using visual studio 2010. When i started developing i gave it a codename and now when it's done i would like to change the applications name, but don't know where to change it (i'm quite new to win32 and visual studio).

I would like to change the .exe name and description (displayed in taskmanager), the name display in the notification area (now it shows MyCodeNameApplication.exe insted of MyCodeNameApplication).

I would also like to give a description, version and author name (so when installing it doesn't say unknown provider).

How can i change this things?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit the version resource in your .rc file.

Comment: can you explain a bit more, i looked in .rc file and i didn't find anything. i've also tried adding a new win32 project (so it generates the files) and didn't find any version info in the .rc file.

Comment: You have to add the resource "Version information": in resource editor open .rc file, right-click on the line of existing resource - "Add resource" option should appear.

Comment: added the version info, but Taskmanager and notofication area still showing the old name..

Comment: nevermind VS added tons of rubbish things which didnt set the proper language.

Answer (score 0):

change the path name in 'yourfilename'.dsp

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10608392)

Comment: one minute ago i solved this problem by my self, i have wrote exactly what i did, how do you know this is not the ANSWER!!? i did it like above, that's it!! i solved it and i posted my solution, please try !

Comment: Maybe it solved your particular problem but it certainly isn't the answer to the original question. If your problem if of interest to the wider community, you can start a new question and self-answer it.